# Ruby/FFI: String not getting to *char function argument

Tags: c, ruby, ffi, ruby-ffi

I'm trying to implement with FFI a few functions from the [Darknet library](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet):

```
require 'ffi'

class Image < FFI::Struct
  layout :w, :int
  layout :h, :int
  layout :c, :int
  layout :data, :pointer
end

class Darknet
  extend FFI::Library

  ffi_lib "./libdarknet.so"

  attach_function :load_image_color, [:string, :int, :int], Image

end

image = Darknet.load_image_color("./test.jpg", 0, 0)
```

It seems that the filename string doesn't get through:

```
Cannot load image "(null)"
STB Reason: can't fopen
```

Here are [the function](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/src/image.c#L1482) and [the declaration](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/include/darknet.h#L693).

I'm quite new to FFI, but I've managed to implement other functions without any issue. I must be missing something obvious, if someone can give me pointers (no pun intended)...

Answer (score 0):

A Ruby string is not the same as a C `char *` (or `char []`), which is a null-terminated (the last character is ASCII 0 - `'\0'`) contiguous array of characters, often considered a "string" in c.

Therefore, you will need to convert the ruby string to a pointer, via the macro `StringValueCStr(str)` (where `str` is the String variable `"./test.jpg"`). There is also the option of `StringValuePtr(str)`, which is better in terms of performance, however it is *not completely safe*, as it does not take into account the fact that c strings are null-terminated, and therefore cannot have null-terminators within the string (which Ruby strings allow). `StringValueCStr()` on the other hand does take this into account, and therefore ensures you have a valid c string.

Comment: Your answer seems to apply for a pure C Ruby extension, I'm just trying to make a library wrapper with FFI though... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Etienne Ah, I should have pciked that up from your question. Just to make sure, have you had a look [the FFI examples](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Examples)?